# Creating multiple variables from same dataframe but with different filters - R

Tags: r

I have a list of differently named variables that are created from the same dataset but with different filters applied. Currently, I just named them all manually and applied necessary filters on them but I was wondering if there was a better way to do it? I tried experimenting with a for loop but I'm quite new to R so it's proving a bit tricky! I can't understand how to create new variables within the for loop.

```
var1 <- dataframe %>% filter(filter1) %>% nrow()
var2 <- dataframe %>% filter(filter2) %>% nrow()
var3 <- dataframe %>% filter(filter3) %>% nrow()
var4 <- dataframe %>% filter(filter4) %>% nrow()
```

The problem with doing it manually is that I have around 55 such variables + it makes for too many ugly lines of code.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the data (or a subset) and the specific code you would use?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's a private database for somebody I'm working with so I really can't share it :/

Answer (score 0):

Update:

I've managed to do it with the following code.

```
filter_list <- list("filter1", "filter2", "filter3", "filter4", "filter5")

find_number <- function() {
  
  for (i in filter_list) {
    number <- dataframe %>% filter(colname == i) %>% nrow()
    
    assign(i, number, envir = .GlobalEnv)
  }
  
}
```

I saved the filters in a list and wrote a for loop that iterates through them. Since I needed variables with the same names as the filters, I used assign within the for loop and since I needed the variables in the global environment (and not within the function envir), I used .GlobalEnv.